# Genymotion - unable to connect to the virtual device

Tags: android, ip, virtualbox, genymotion

В интернете очень много информации по поводу это ошибке, но не подошел ни один из предлагаемых. Я испробовал все варианты.

1. Менял статические адреса на динамические в свойствах адаптера.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYzaj9KWyEQ
2. Включал DHCP-сервер и выкл. адаптер, в этом случае "оно" создает новый адаптер и подключается к нему.
   http://madcoda.com/2014/05/solving-genymotion-unable-to-connect-to-your-virtual-device-error/
3. Переустанавливал и Genymotion и VM, удалял образы смартфоном и пересоздавал их.
4. Удалял адаптеры на вкладке host-only networks, шаг 2 по этой ссылке. Ни один шаг мне не помог.
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922077/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device
5. Отключал интернет и пробовал без него, то же самое.

IPv4/IPv4 Mask : 198.168.160.1/255.255.255.0

DHCP-server IP/Mask: 198.168.160.100/255.255.255.0
Lower/Upper: 198.168.160.101/198.168.160.254

В логах gemymotion пытается подключаться по Lower IP всегда. И потом вылетаем ошибка. Я пытаюсь запустить эмулятор API 22, но 17 и ниже API запускаются нормально. При этом они подключаются к 198.168.160.102 - где вообще указывается этот адрес.

Читал, что у некоторых не запускаются образы в самом Genymotion, в то время как в Virtual Box все хорошо, у меня и там и там не запускается, VB пишет адрес по которому совершалась попытка подключится, иногда это 10.0.3.15 и строчку

```
make sure that the v86d helper is installed and executable
```

гугл говорит, что это VB поставлена криво, но я уже столько раз ее переустанавливал, и все чистил после деинстала.

Comment: У меня была проблема с VB (не запускался) на Windows, проблему решил отключением Hyper-V. Может быть еще из за того что VB скачан с торрента и кривой.

Comment: @AdamLuisSean
 Я с оф. сайта качал, а где отлючить Hyper-V?

Comment: Программы и компоненты-> Включение/отключение компонентов(слева) ->Снять галочку с Hyper-v. Гляньте еще [тут](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx) и [тут](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/42041-hyper-v-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: @AdamLuisSean Почитал, очень полезные ссылки, выключил Hyper-V, теперь все работает. Спасибо! Напишите ответ на этот пост, я отмечу его как правильный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо отключить Hyper-V, так как возникает конфликт.